# Cannot clear java class from memory

Tags: java, matlab

I have a simple java class as shown below:

```
public class Add2Numbers 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num1=2, num2=4, sum;
        sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("Sum of these numbers: "+sum);
    }
}
```

I compile the class and run in matlab using:

```
obj = Add2Numbers;
javaMethod('main', o,"");
```

and I get the output: **Sum of these numbers: 6** which is, of course, correct.

Next I change the code in my text editor (e.g. set **num1=4**) compile, execute the clear statements below:

```
clear all
clear java
clear import
clear CLASSES
clear ALL
clear
```

then run again:

```
obj = Add2Numbers;
javaMethod('main', o,"");
```

But the calculation result remains the same as before. If I close and restart MATLAB the modified java class runs correctly.  So how on earth do I clear a java class without having to close MATLAB and restart it? 
set

Comment: the main method is static and that means it is loaded and stays in memory till the app quits.

Comment: `clear java` only clears the obj on dynamic path. Does it work if you add class folder to dynamic path, rather than preferment path?

Comment: I removed "static" from the main but the results are the same as before.

Comment: Xiangrui - please explain how to add to a dynamic path.